# cloud foundry caching of node_modules

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

Caching of node modules is enabled by default in cloud foundry node buildpack deployments

```
  NODE_MODULES_CACHE: true
```

How does it know how to cache dependencies? If I modify my shrinkwrap file or my package.json does it install the entire list of dependencies again? Or does it cache dependencies based on each individual module listed in the package.json file.

Answer (score 1):

The buildpack is basically caching your `node_modules` directory. Then it's up to npm to figure out what to download/reuse when the buildpack runs `npm install`, much like what happens when you are working locally.

If you change node.js or npm versions then the entire cache is invalidated.